# Marginal effects plot with PCSE using plm package

Tags: r, plm, marginal-effects

Does anyone have any advice on how to make a marginal effects plot in R using panel corrected standard errors?

To estimate panel corrected standard errors in R, I use the plm and lmtest packages.

First I estimate the regression model with plm:

```
plm <- plm(Y ~ X*Z, data = a, model='pooling', index=c('cicode', 'year'))
```

Then I pass this plm object through coeftest using the lmtest package:

```
plm2 <- coeftest(plm, vcov=function(x) vcovBK(x,type="HC1", cluster="time"))
```

plm2 then contains a list of the coefficients and panel corrected standard errors.  What package and code could I use to then create a marginal effects plot using plm2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131824/r-packages-effects-plm-error-in-contrasts-when-trying-to-plot-marginal-eff

Comment: The above thread does not include an answer to my question concerning marginal effects plots with panel corrected standard errors.  That threat is based on plotting a plm object, but I am looking for help plotting a coeftest object from the lmtest package.

Comment: I am sorry if it doen't answer your question. But, there should be in CV.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  What does CV mean?

Comment: Its cross validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/