# Combining Effects and PLM package when using factor variables.

Tags: r, effects, plm

I am trying to use the effects package to extract predicted values for a PLM Model. Unfortunately, as soon as I include a factor variable, the effects package breaks down with the error message

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
‘range’ not meaningful for factors
```

Has anyone found a way to work around this problem?

Here is a minimum working example that replicates the issue

```
data("Produc", package = "plm")

Produc$dummy1<-(rbinom(nrow(Produc), 1 , 0.4)) #Generate Random Dummy
Produc$dummy2<-as.factor(Produc$dummy1)


mod1 <- plm(gsp ~ pcap * dummy1,data = Produc, index = c("state","year"), model="fd")
mod2 <- plm(gsp ~ pcap * dummy2,data = Produc, index = c("state","year"), model="fd")

Effect(c("pcap","dummy1"),mod1) #This works 
Effect(c("pcap","dummy2"),mod2) #This does not
```

This might be related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131824/r-packages-effects-plm-error-in-contrasts-when-trying-to-plot-marginal-eff), but the error is different.

Comment: Maybe, the `effects` package cannot cope with `plm`-objects? As a workaround, you can always "simulate" the panel models with `lm()`. Either transform the data yourself or use `pmodel.response()` and `plm:::model.matrix()` (the latter does not seem to be exported, thus `plm:::`) to get the transformed data on which you can run `lm()`.

Comment: On the other hand: The warning makes sense: if `dummy2` is a factor, it can only be specific values, in this case 0 and 1. Thus, it does not make sense to calculate effects for other value than 0 and 1.Try `allEffects(mod2)` is that what you want?